# Submit button triggers the get submit before the ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm very new to Ajax, so this is my first try to bind laravel and Ajax together. Anyway I've understood what it's all about and everything, but when I try to post data using a submit button, the data is delivered as a get method, it's as if the code never gets to the ajax function.

Here is My form :

```
<form id="addtocart">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit">add to cart</button>
            <input id="name" type="hidden" value="{{$one->name}}" name="data">
            <input id="price" type="hidden" value="{{$one->price}}" name="price">
            <input id="image" type="hidden" value="{{$one->image_path}}" name="image">
</form>
```

My Ajax Function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#addtocart').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('/addtocart') }}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
           name: jQuery('#name').val(),
           image: jQuery('#image').val(),
           price: jQuery('#price').val()
        },
        success: function(result){
           jQuery('.alert').show();
           jQuery('.alert').html(result.success);
        }});
     });
  });
```

Thanks for your help !!! (I thought  that the script wasn't running at first because I was including the jquery library after the ajax function .. But that wasn't the case)

Comment: Do you see anything in developers console?

Comment: Do you mean like errors?

Comment: at the end of the submit closure function (below the ajax) put `return false;` and check if that helps better than `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Errors, also check that ajax request runs.

Comment: nope didn't help

Comment: No the ajax request doesn't run at all that's the problem ... it's not even getting to the script code

Comment: do you have the JS within your view? is it surrounded by a `<script>` tag? And also have you checked the Console of the browser for any errors if jQuery is not loaded at all.

Comment: @nakov , I don't have the JS within my view , I've put in the layout that I'm using. Yes and I've already checked the browser console, the jquery is working as fine, in fact I'm using for other stuff in the same view !!

Comment: Did you debug the jQuery code that submit function is calling or not?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you're saying

Comment: This part of your code seems to be quiet right. I think this happened because of an other conflict in your page. It's good to see whole page you've created.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `method="post"` inside `form` tag

```
<form id="addtocart" method="post">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit">add to cart</button>
            <input id="name" type="hidden" value="{{$one->name}}" name="data">
            <input id="price" type="hidden" value="{{$one->price}}" name="price">
            <input id="image" type="hidden" value="{{$one->image_path}}" name="image">
</form>
```

Hope it will be work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an id to your button

```
<button id="addtocart" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit">add to cart</button>
```

and then assign the event listener to the button click instead:

```
jQuery('#addtocart').on('click', function(e){}); // the closure body should be the same.
```

Comment: I was using this in the first place ... But that wasn't the problem

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

In your form tag, assign the action attribute to a hashtag value.

```
<form id="addtocart" action="#">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit">add to cart</button>
            <input id="name" type="hidden" value="{{$one->name}}" name="data">
            <input id="price" type="hidden" value="{{$one->price}}" name="price">
            <input id="image" type="hidden" value="{{$one->image_path}}" name="image">
</form>
```

Without it, the form will execute traditionally first, thats why the ajax script isn't catching the submit function.